# How to change cells color on datagridview based on string values using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview filled by a local database. This datagridview has some columns with 2 types of values: "OK" and "NO".
I'd like to color cells with "OK" value in green and cells with "NO" values in red.

At the moment I am trying just with one column and I make a code but it's not working

This is my code:

```
 private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
 {
     if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.Equals("over05"))
     {
         if (e.Value != null)
         {
             if (((string)e.Value).Trim() == "OK")
                 e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;

             if (((string)e.Value).Trim() == "NO")
                 e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
     }
 }
```

Unfortunatelly I didn't get any color on that column with that values

Thank you

Comment: Tried your code and it did change the colors for me. Did you try debugging it? If you do not reach the breakpoint, you should check, if the event handler is really listening for the cellformatting event. if you reach the check point: step through your variables.

Comment: As mentioned, this is an issue resolved by debugging your code. As a note, since your data is coming from a database, you should check `if (e.Value != DBNull.Value && e.Value != null)` (`null` and `DbNull.Value` are not the same thing). Make sure that the Header' text matches the actual case. Possibly compare the Columns, as in `var dgv = sender as DataGridView; if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == dgv.Columns["<The name of the Column>"])`